# Slow retrieval of blob field when using PHP prepared statements with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In the spirit of improving security, I have implemented a function that executes prepared statements.

But I am running into problems when I try to fetch base64 encoded blob contents (around 30-50KB).

If I run the query without using prepared statements, it runs quickly.

With the prepared statement, it stalls when calling: `mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)`
and takes nearly a minute or more to run, eventually returning a result.

As soon as I get rid of the `mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)` call or exclude the blob field from my select query, things run quickly like usual.

I am hoping someone has an idea of what is going on here. I have dredged the interwebs looking for an answer with little luck thus far.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver to me. But what is the blob for in the first place? Maybe you can also provide the full code of the two different queries ($statement).

Comment: The app uses an api call that returns data without a schema. The schema-less data is stuffed into a blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save the binary blob in something else than MySQL, keeping a simple identifier in MySQL so that I know where to fetch it.
MySQL is never a preferred way of storing large chunks of binary data.
At least it would solve your problem and you should probably try to ditch the base64 overhead (which also adds 33% in size).

Another solution I would try is to see if there is a more recent version of the driver or server. Alternatively trying a different driver such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

A third solution would be to try changing the field type from BLOB to TEXT, base64 is within the normal ascii range.

Comment: I just excluded the blob for now. But will most likely hit this issue again, so I will have to see about testing a different driver to see what happens. Many programmers in my department throw a lot of values like this in MySQL (boo, bad practice, I know) because they do not have access to a central file store, like HDFS or some other high availability data store. So alas, we have hacked ourselves into a corner for now.